# Can we convert perl regular expression to POSIX regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl, posix

I have a regular expression following perl language in one application.I want to convert it to POSIX before running in other application.
I dont know whether it is possible or not. so does anyone have any idea on this?

the regex is:

`[^@\s]`  /in perl

`[^@[:space:]]` /in POSIX

Comment: Is `[^@[:space:]]` not working for you?

Comment: no its working. but the problem is i cant change the regex. i have two application which uses the same regex. but both follow different language. so i have to change entire code in any of them. Hence, i want to know whether their is any regex conversion possible?

Comment: Hmm if you want some automatic converted from PCRE to POSIX then I don't think it is possible since PCRE features are different.

Comment: thank you. Then the only way left is to change the code?

Comment: Another way is to list out every character matched by `\s` or `[:space:]`. Note that the short-hand character class may change its behavior depending on the mode, so you need to take that into consideration.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but i didnt get it properly. what should i do after listing. what is mode?. pls help me to understand

Answer (score 3):

Perl understand POSIX character classes in double brackets. So `[^@[[:space:]]]` is equivalent to `[^@\s]` (as long as `[[:space:]]` is the same as `\s` which I am not quite sure).

Can you re-write the Perl regexp with POSIX character classes? Then it would be easier to go from one to the other.

Comment: Thank u for your suggestion.[:space:] is equal to [\t\r\n\v\f] and in perl which intern follow unicode its [\p{Z}\t\r\n\v\f]. i think both are same . And i replaced \s with [[:space:]], its not working.([for [:space:]its working fine). but my doubt is will it work on that application which is following perl

Comment: I wasn't clear: what I said was: `[[:space:]]` works in Perl. So you don't need `[^@\s]` in Perl, you can use `[^@[[:space:]]]` instead, which is much closer to the POSIX version, and maybe can be converted automatically.

Comment: ya. i checked in many regex tools [:space:] works for perl also. thank you so much.

Comment: oh, you're right, since it's already in a character class, you only need 1 set of brackets so `[^@[:space:]]` is fine, no need to transform it at all.